# How to GROUP GROUP_CONCAT()?

Tags: php, mysql

I am looking for a way to get groups of the GROUP_CONCAT() function in a single query, for example.

My current code

```
SELECT
    SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(service_info.ip_address SEPARATOR ','),',',service_plans.aggregation) AS ip_address
FROM
    services
LEFT JOIN
    service_info
ON
    service_info.service_id = services.id
LEFT JOIN
    service_plans
ON
    service_plans.id = services.service_plan_id
WHERE
    service_plans.id = '2'
```

I want to group the IP addresses by a specific number(the $group_by variable if you see in the query) but then separate by a different character such as ":" or something.

Essentially I want my output to look like:

If $group_by=2: 10.1.1.2,10.1.1.3:10.1.1.4,10.1.1.5

If $group_by=3: 10.1.1.2,10.1.1.3,10.1.1.4:10.1.1.5

Is this possible to implement into my current query?

**UPDATE:** table structure

Table `service_plans`

     `id | name                 | aggregation
    -----------------------------------------
     1  | Uncapped 10Mbps 20:1 | 20
     2  | Uncapped 20Mbps 10:1 | 10
     3  | Capped 30Mbps        | 0`

Table `services`

     `id | service_plan_id | description
    ------------------------------------
     1  | 2               | Phone
     2  | 2               | Laptop
     3  | 2               | PC
     4  | 2               | TV
     5  | 2               | Test`

Table `service_info`

     `id | service_id | ip_address
    ------------------------------
     1  | 1          | 10.1.1.2
     2  | 2          | 10.1.1.3
     3  | 3          | 10.1.1.4
     4  | 4          | 10.1.1.5
     5  | 5          | 10.1.1.6`

I am trying to get an array of ip_address's concatenated and separated by a comma but the in groups of however much the `service_plans.aggregation` value is.

If aggregation is 2, then my output should be:
10.1.1.2,10.1.1.3:10.1.1.4,10.1.1.5
As you can see they are in groups of 2 and then the next group is separated by a colon(:)

If aggregation is 3, then my output should be:
10.1.1.2,10.1.1.3,10.1.1.4:10.1.1.5
As you can see they are in groups of 3 and then the next group is separated by a colon(:) and so on

Answer (score 0):

Your post is a little confusing. What would be helpful is if you posted sample data, and then posted what you want your query to return. I'll give you an answer to what I think you're asking, based on the subject of your post.

ServicePlanIPs

```
service_plan_id | ip_address
-------------------------------
 1              | 192.168.70.1
 1              | 192.168.70.2
 1              | 192.168.70.3
 2              | 192.168.70.4
 2              | 192.168.70.5
 2              | 192.168.70.6
```

If you run this query against ServicePlanIPs:

```
SELECT service_plan_id, GROUP_CONCAT(ip_address) as ip_addresses
FROM ServicePlanIPs
GROUP BY service_plan_id
```

You will get:

```
service_plan_id | ip_addresses
-------------------------------
 1              | 192.168.70.1, 192.168.70.2, 192.168.70.3
 2              | 192.168.70.4, 192.168.70.5, 192.168.70.6
```

Comment: I have updated my question, hopefully that should help you better understand what I'm looking for?

Answer (score 0):

I don't guarantee this will run out of the box, but it should get you on the right track. Hope it helps. Note - if you're using a version of mysql which supports window functions, you can do something similar to the below and use the natively supported RANK function instead of doing it manually with variables.

```
SET @curRank := 0;
SET @concatIps := '';

SELECT 
sp.id,
@curRank := @curRank + 1 AS rank,
IF(MOD(@curRank, (SELECT aggregation FROM service_plans WHERE id = {service_plan_id}) = 0, @concatIps := CONCAT(@concatIps, ':', s.ip_address), @concatIps := CONCAT(@concatIps, ',', s.ip_address)) 
FROM service_plans sp 
JOIN services s
    ON sp.id = s.service_plan_id
JOIN service_info si
    ON si.service_id = s.id
WHERE sp.id = {service_plan_id}
ORDER BY service_info_id
```